# What's wrong with declaration of this routed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

I've created the following UserControl:

```
public partial class ReplacementPatternEditor : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ....

    public static readonly RoutedEvent CollectionChanged = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "CollectionChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ReplacementPatternEditor));

    void RaiseCollectionChangedEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ReplacementPatternEditor.CollectionChanged);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, when I try to use this routed event inside my xaml code:

```
<local:ReplacementPatternEditor ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}" CollectionChanged="OnCollectionChanged"/>
```

I'm getting following error at compilation:

```
The property 'CollectionChanged' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MyNamespace'
```

Why am I getting this, and how do I make the routed events work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx). It talks about registering a handler which you have done, then it talks about providing the CLR Accessors for the event which I don't see in your code. Then it adds the Event handler.  You do not have an Event declaration

i.e. something like this

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent CollectionChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( 
    "CollectionChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ReplacementPatternEditor)); 

public event RoutedEventHandler CollectionChanged
{
    add { AddHandler(CollectionChangedEvent, value); } 
    remove { RemoveHandler(CollectionChangedEvent, value); }
}


void RaiseCollectionChangedEvent() 
{ 
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ReplacementPatternEditor.CollectionChanged); 
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs); 
}
```